# (Re)definition of commands that use delimiters other than braces (e.g. \underbrace)

Tags: tex-core, delimiters

How do you go about redefining a command such as `\underbrace`, which uses an "uncommon" delimiter, i.e. `_`, between its two arguments, so that the redefined command be usable in exactly the same way as the original one?

As an example, consider the command `\redub` ("red underbrace") defined below on the basis of `\underbrace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\redub[2]{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    \color{red}%
    \underbrace{\color{currentcolor}#1}_{\color{red}#2}%
    \color{currentcolor}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \redub{e^{-x^2}}{\text{foo}} + \redub{e^{-2x^2}}{\text{bar}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For someone who commonly uses `\underbrace`, it would be much easier to be able to use the command just like `\underbrace`, i.e. like this:

`\redub{}_{}`;

not like that:

`\redub{}{}`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
\newcommand{\redub}{} % make sure it's definable
\def\redub#1_#2{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    \color{red}%
    \underbrace{\color{currentcolor}#1}_{\color{red}#2}%
    \color{currentcolor}%
}
```

using lower level features.

You might want to add a check for a missing `_`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\redub}{} % make sure it's definable
\def\redub#1{%
  \@ifnextchar_%
    {\@redub{#1}}
    {\@latex@warning{Missing argument for \string\redub}\@redub{#1}_{}}%
}
\def\@redub#1_#2{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    \color{red}%
    \underbrace{\color{currentcolor}#1}_{\color{red}#2}%
    \color{currentcolor}%
}
\makeatother
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\redub}{} % make sure it's definable
\def\redub#1{%
  \@ifnextchar_%
    {\@redub{#1}}
    {\@latex@warning{Missing argument for \string\redub}\@redub{#1}_{}}%
}
\def\@redub#1_#2{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    \color{red}%
    \underbrace{\color{currentcolor}#1}_{\color{red}#2}%
    \color{currentcolor}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \redub{e^{-x^2}}_{\text{foo}} + \redub{e^{-2x^2}}_{\text{bar}}
\]

$\redub{A}X$
\end{document}
```

[image]