# Double superscript/subscript issue with macros

Tags: subscripts

I would like to be able to define a macro like `\newcommand{\Zs}{Z^*}` and then somewhere within the text say `$\Zs^T$` and have the effect of writing `$Z^{* T}$`. It should also be possible to write `$\Zs$` without the subscript. Is there a simple solution to make this possible? Preferably, the solution should allow one to do this for many symbols with relative ease.

I guess one way is to define a macro with an argument like `\newcommand{\Zss}[1]{Z^{* #1}}` and the use either `$\Zss{}$` or `$\Zss{T}$`, but this does not seem very elegant.

Can we define a blueprint command, called `starred` so that whenever we want a starred symbol, we can write `\newcommand\Xs{\starred{X}}`?

Comment: related: [(Re)definition of commands that use delimiters other than braces (e.g. \underbrace)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103337/redefinition-of-commands-that-use-delimiters-other-than-braces-e-g-underbra)

Comment: The answers below are impressive but seem like a pain to implement. For my purposes, it was easier to just attach the extra subscripts/superscripts to some empty braces: `\Zs{}^T`. I don't expect this is robust when used for large/complicated macros, but it works for me and requires no machinery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Updated answer

Use the `e` argument type.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definegenericstarred}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { ##1s } { \genericstarred{##1} }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\genericstarred}{me{^_}}{%
  #1^{*\IfValueT{#2}{#2}}\IfValueT{#3}{_{#3}}%
}

\definegenericstarred{X,Y,Z,W}

\begin{document}

$\Xs+\Zs^T+\Ws+\Ys^2$

$\Xs_1+\Zs^T_1+\Ws+\Ys^2_1$

$\Xs_1+\Zs_1^T+\Ws+\Ys_1^2$

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Old answer (superseded by the new one)

You have to be disciplined and write, if a subscript is needed,

```
\Zs^{<superscript>}_{<subscript>}
```

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\passerby@genericstarred}[1]{%
  #1\@ifnextchar^\passerby@eathat{^*}%
}
\def\passerby@eathat#1#2{% #1 is ^
  ^{*#2}%
}
\newcommand{\definegenericstarred}[1]{%
  \@for\next:=#1\do{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname\next s\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\passerby@genericstarred{\next}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\definegenericstarred{X,Y,Z,W}

\begin{document}
$\Xs+\Zs^T+\Ws+\Ys^2$
\end{document}
```

---

The same with LaTeX3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definegenericstarred}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { ##1s } { \passerby_generic_starred:n { ##1 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \passerby_generic_starred:n #1
 {
  #1 % print the main letter
  \peek_catcode_remove:NTF ^ % check if a ^ follows 
   { \passerby_add_star:n }  % yes, add the * to the explicit superscript
   { ^{*} }                  % no, just add the *
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \passerby_add_star:n #1
 {
  ^{*#1} % the final superscript
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definegenericstarred{X,Y,Z,W}

\begin{document}
$\Xs+\Zs^T+\Ws+\Ys^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. I couldn't understand what you mean by being disciplined though. You mean if I need a subscript I have to include the braces around both super- and subscripts?

Comment: It’s been 7 years of LaTeX development since this answer was written, and you might want to update it with the `e`-type so that you no longer have to be as “disciplined” with the order of `^` and `_`.

Comment: @Gaussler Really so!

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX's `\newcommand` is limiting in the delimiters it allows. For more general macros, you need to use TeX's `\def`. I refer you to [egreg's comprehensive answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103338/21891)  to [(Re)definition of commands that use delimiters other than braces (e.g. \underbrace)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103337/redefinition-of-commands-that-use-delimiters-other-than-braces-e-g-underbra).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% sanity check (causes an error if \Zs is already defined as LaTeX command)
\newcommand{\Zs}{} 

\makeatletter
\def\Zs{%
  \@ifnextchar^%
    {\@Zs}
    {\@latex@warning{Missing argument for \string\Zs}\@Zs^{}}%
}
\def\@Zs^#1{%
  Z^{* #1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
foo $\Zs^T$ bar $\Zs$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if the OP just wants to write `\Zs` without the additional superscript?

Comment: @A.Ellett That's not part of the question, but I'll edit my answer to handle that case.

Comment: @Jubobs, thanks. Actually, being able to write both versions, with and without the superscript, is my question. It is important that one can still write `Zs` without superscript.

Comment: @passerby51 See my edit. However, your question is unclear  as to whether you want the argument of `\Zs` to be optional. You should edit your question for clarification.

Comment: Also, let us say that I want to to define many of these, `\Xs, \Ys, \Zs, \Ws`, etc. Is it possible to make the above code into a blueprint for generating multiple such symbols, without rewriting everything from scratch.

Comment: @passerby51 What syntax would you like for such a macro? In particular, how would you like to specify the letter to use (e.g. `X`,`Y`,`Z`, or `W`)?

Comment: @Jubobs, Let us say I want to have a command that takes argument `X` and produces the starred version `\Xs`.

Comment: @passerby51 Yes, but what *how* would you like to pass X to that macro "to rule them all"? What delimiters should this macro use?

Comment: @Jubobs, Can a `starred` command be defined so that whenever I want a starred symbol I can write `\newcommand\Xs{\starred{X}}`

Comment: @passerby51 I understand. Yes, it is possible, but you should add your last comment into your question for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to write a comment so posting as an answer.
Try `{\Zs}^T`. It looks like the curly brackets forces the `\Zs` to act as an independent entity therefore avoiding the double superscript problem.

Edit: There seems to be another problem here. Since the second superscript is applied with `\Zs` as the body, the second superscript shows up bigger than the first one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).